# Java Programming Validation (GUI)

Tags: java, class, user-interface, panel

i am doing a project in which i have 3 classes (lamp, clock and TV) now,

i am making a GUI Application which will allow users to add lamps, tv's and clocks to a 3.3 grid panel,

in terms of validation, one of the constructors of the Clock class allows the user to initiate a Clock with hour minute and second parameters passed into it, as well as various setters

would it be best to have the validation inside these classes (i.e. ensuring user cannot make a clock which reads 24:01:01 etc) or is it advisable to have the validation at the GUI level i.e if asked to enter a time to initiate the clock, if it is wrong, simply display the panel again until valid input is applied.

based on experience, which is the best advisable way to do this?

(i am a first year Computer Scientist studying java, bare that in mind when responding as im not familiar with deep technical methods)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You would want validation on both levels.

You want validation on the model side (the `Clock` class) to avoid invalid data in your model.

However, to offer a good user experience you also want validation in the UI so that the user immediately sees that his/her input is invalid and not has to wait until his/her input reaches  the model.

Compare it with a web application: you want validation on the front-end to offer quick feedback to your user. You also want server-side validation to avoid that somebody bypasses your UI and inserts invalid data in your model.

Comment: aaah okay :D, i was thinking of this, but i wasnt sure if the double validation would be over the top in a sense, 

i think i may have the parameter intake constructor create a no-args clock if an invalid input managed to get past the GUI validation in that case, sound reasonable?

thanks for the reply by the way :D